# remove whitespaces inside XML tag with java

Tags: java, xml

I am getting XML with the following tags. What I do is, read the XML file with Java using Sax parser and save them to database. but it seems that spaces are there after the p tag like below.

```
     <Inclusions><![CDATA[<p>                                               </p><ul> <li>Small group walking tour</li> <li>Entrance fees</li> <li>Professional guide </li> <li>Guaranteed to skip the long lines</li> <li>Headsets to hear the guide clearly</li> </ul>
                <p></p>]]></Inclusions>
```

But when we insert the read string to the database(PostgreSQL 8) it is printing bad charactors like below for those spaces.

> \011\011\011\011\011\011\011\011\011\011\011\011
>
> - Small
>     group walking tour
> - Entrance fees
> - Professional guide
> - Guaranteed to skip the long lines
> - Headsets to hear
>     the guide clearly
>
> \012\011\011\011\011\011

1. I want to know why it is printing bad characters(011\011) like that ?
2. What is the best way to remove spaces inside XML tags with java? (Or how to prevent those bad characters.)

I have checked samples and most of them with python samples.

This is how the XML reads with SAX in my program,

Method 1

```
  // ResultHandler is the class that used to read the XML. 
  ResultHandler handler         = new ResultHandler();
   // Use the default parser
  SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    // Retrieve the XML file
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFile)); // input file is XML.
    // Parse the XML input
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    saxParser.parse( in , handler);
```

This is how the ResultHandler class used to read the XML as Sax parser with Method-1

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

// other imports

    class ResultHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public void startDocument ()
        {
            logger.debug("Start document");         
        }

        public void endDocument ()
        {
            logger.debug("End document");
        }

        public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes attribs)
        throws SAXException {           
            strValue = "";      
            // add logic with start of tag. 
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
            //logger.debug("characters");
            strValue += new String(ch, start, length);
            //logger.debug("strValue-->"+strValue);
        }

        public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {           
            // add logic to end of tag. 
        }
    }
```

So that need to know, how to set setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true) or similar with sax parser.

Comment: With the google checking identified that   input.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim(); would be solutions for this. But the major problem is why printing bad charactors for space ?

And with this method, we have to correct each and every XML tag ? Is there general solutions for that to sort out entire XML ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set for your `DocumentBuilderFactory`

[`setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28boolean%29)

because of this:

> Due to reliance on the content model this setting requires the parser
>   to be in validating mode

you also need to set

[`setValidating(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating%28boolean%29)

Or the `str= str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` might as well work

Comment: Please let me know, how can we set that property to the following coding.                                                                ResultHandler oHandler        = new ResultHandler();  
  CreateParser parser        = new CreateParser(oHandler);  
  
  InputSource input         = null;  
  try{   
   input           = new InputSource(new StringReader(this.responeXml)); 
   input.setEncoding("UTF-8");    
   parser.parse(input);
  }catch (Exception e) {   
   logger.error("-------------Exception in parse-----------",e);
  }

Comment: @RuchiraKariyawasam, I'm having difficulties finding your ResultHandler and CreateParser classes that you are using. Can you please tell me what libraries are you using?

Comment: @Andrel I have edit my questions to use only method 1. These are the imports that used in my class.                            import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

Comment: Okay, being looking over this. Looks like there is a method in ContentHandler ignorableWhitespaces, but you won't use it anyway. In characters() you could easily do a trim()...but the problem you cannot eliminate the whitespaces because of the CDATA tag, that is blocking to do a trim. There is soomething out there trying to get data from CDATA, using a stack : http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/org.xml.sax/accessing-character-data-cdata-of-xml-element-2.html . You can try it, I did not have too much luck. Hope this will help you on the direction to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm also finding an exact answer. But think this will help for u.
   The C/Modula-3 octal notation; vs there meaning in [this link](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html)
   It says

   - \011 is for Horizontal tab (ASCII HT)
   - \012 is for Line feed (ASCII NL, newline)
2. You can replace multiple spaces with one space as follows

   str = str.replaceAll("\s([\s])+", " ");

Comment: Good link, so that get the clue what is the cause of this.